# Is it possible to solve a simple equation involving linear and exponential components?

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving

To keep it general, I want to solve

$$ a = t - be^{ct} $$

where $a, b\text{ and }c$ are known real numbers. I cannot find an analytical solution for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and I am wondering if there is one.

Comment: it should be solving for $t$?

Comment: oh, yes. I just edited to make it a bit more explicit.

Comment: i have written a possible solution for you!

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Lambert function ! Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function for a very good introduction and several examples of the kind of manipulations to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a solution with the known elementary functions is not possible, we Can write
$$x=\frac{a c-W\left(-b c e^{a
   c}\right)}{c}$$
where $W$ denotes the Lambert W function

Comment: ok, double checking with the wikipedia page cited above I got the same answer. Thank you very much.